# Homebrew path variable for Xcode

Tags: xcode, homebrew

I recently updated HB on both my and my wife's machine. The former is Intel and the later is M1, so the libs are in different places, `/opt/homebrew/`... vs. `/usr/local/`... This makes adding the header search a bit annoying in Xcode, and now my builds are failing as it can't find the libs in `/opt`... on my machine.

I seem to recall there is a shell variable one can use in this situation, not `$PATH` but another one like `$HOMEBREWPATH` or similar that is automatically created? I recall seeing it mentioned when I did the install on the M1, but now I can't find a hint of this anywhere, and of course, Google returns beer.

Am I imagining this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to probably use [`$(brew --prefix)`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#--prefix---unbrewed---installed-formula-).

As for the shell variable you're referring to, it's `HOMEBREW_PREFIX`. I'd be a bit more cautious of this since it requires [`brew shellenv`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#shellenv) to have been evaluated.

> Consider adding evaluation of this command’s output to your dotfiles (e.g. ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.zprofile) with: eval "$(brew shellenv)"

Comment: This is certainly what I was thinking of. Do you know of a way to use this in Xcode? The editor "breaks" on the space before --preview and rewrites it as two lines and then fails. I tried a couple of different quoting mechanisms in Terminal, but they all failed to return the correct string.

Comment: Thanks for marking the solution. I'm not sure about Xcode. Since you control both machines, you could ensure `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` has been set or manually define another env variable? e.g. `export BREW_PATH=$(brew --prefix)`